# Django sort topics into first letter blocks with pinned items at the top

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a page that displays all the boards on my forum site and sorts them into blocks based by the first letter. The output looks something like this:

**A**

Apple

Attack

**B**

Banana

etc...

```
{% regroup boards|dictsort:"name" by name.0 as item_letter %}
<ul>
    {% for letter in item_letter %}
        <h2>{{ letter.grouper|title }}</h2>
        {% for i in letter.list|dictsort:"name" %}
            <li>{{ i.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% empty %}
        <p><a href="/boards/new">Create a board</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However some boards are pinned and should appear at the top of the block:

**A**

(pinned) Attack

Apple

etc...

The main issue here is the code above overrides the order of the queryset (as it is currently designed to) and pinned items do not appear at the top of their blocks. How should I rework this?

```
boards = Board.objects.all().order_by('-pinned')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try pass 2 resultset instead one

```
boards_pinned = Board.objects.filter(pinned=True).order_by('name')
boards = Board.objects.filter(pinned=False).order_by('name')
```

then iterate `boards_pinned` and `boards` like what you did on your template